# heroku upload error Could not detect rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to upload my app to heroku for now its just pure design with no need for database connection. I keep on getting this error when uploading.

```
Your bundle is complete!
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
remote:        Bundle completed (1.06s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Could not detect rake tasks
remote:        ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app with no environment variables present
remote:        and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): ://user:pass@127.0.0.1/dbname
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:176:in `split'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:211:in `parse'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:747:in `parse'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:35:in `initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:279:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:279:in `resolve_url_connection'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:242:in `resolve_string_connection'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:267:in `resolve_hash_connection'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:228:in `resolve_connection'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:152:in `resolve'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:164:in `block in resolve_all'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:163:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:163:in `resolve_all'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:69:in `resolve'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/core.rb:46:in `configurations='
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/core.rb:48:in `block in <module:Core>'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/concern.rb:120:in `class_eval'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/concern.rb:120:in `append_features'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:297:in `include'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:297:in `<class:Base>'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:282:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:39:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:39:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:237:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:237:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:245:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:245:in `each_registered_block'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:237:in `run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:373:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:13:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:13:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:373:in `run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:449:in `load_tasks'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_1f483b69aed84c97fc81983578b0b4e9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `load'
remote:        vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `<main>'
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> (none)
remote:        Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, web, worker
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 30.6MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v14
remote:        https://teknolohiya.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/teknolohiya.git
   897dd11..5ac0b58  master -> master
```

it finished and says upload complete but when trying to check the application it shows 
application error 
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do  
  #root
  root 'home#index'

  #welcome
  get 'welcome' => 'welcome#index'

  #about
  get 'about' => 'about#index'  

  #contact
  get 'contact' => 'contact#index'  

end
```

Comment: Can you show me task here

Comment: what version of rails?

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this and maybe not the issue for you but the problem is that Heroku is trying to call to the DATABASE_URL. I provisioned a free postgres db (even though we dont use it for the project) and was able to get around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs (heroku logs)
Check the network response using google chrome developer tool (right click, inspect element).

I am looking at this error

`URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): ://user:pass@127.0.0.1/dbname`

I will guess it has to do with your routes. Show your routes.rb file Did you state the root of your site? 

`root 'welcome#index'`

Comment: Can you show the logs? run `heroku logs` .This is a good step by step guide from [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#introduction)